# Google Chrome does not display the cover page when loading a carousel video I wrote?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote a static website that has a video carousel function and uses the poster attribute, but the cover will not be displayed when Google Chrome loads, and the loading is very slow, but the cover will flash when it is refreshed. Will not be displayed. However, this problem does not occur in Firefox, and the loading speed is also OK. Ask everyone what is going on? ?

```js
$(function(){
var click=0;
var right=0;      //解决第一次右边点击没反应
$('.video>div:last-child').click(function(){    //当点击左边按钮
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[i].pause();}
click+=1;
if(click>=6)click=1;
right=1;
$('.video li:nth-of-type('+(((click+0)<=5) ? (click+0) : (click+0-5))+')').attr('class','video5');
$('.video li:nth-of-type('+(((click+1)<=5) ? (click+1) : (click+1-5))+')').attr('class','video1');
$('.video li:nth-of-type('+(((click+2)<=5) ? (click+2) : (click+2-5))+')').attr('class','video2');
$('.video li:nth-of-type('+(((click+3)<=5) ? (click+3) : (click+3-5))+')').attr('class','video3');
$('.video li:nth-of-type('+(((click+4)<=5) ? (click+4) : (click+4-5))+')').attr('class','video4');
})
$('.video>div:first-child').click(function(){  //当点击右边按钮
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[i].pause();}
click-=1;
if(click<=0)click=5;
if(!right)click=4;  //解决第一次右边点击没反应
right=1;
$('.video li:nth-of-type('+(((click+0)<=5) ? (click+0) : (click+0-5))+')').attr('class','video5');
$('.video li:nth-of-type('+(((click+1)<=5) ? (click+1) : (click+1-5))+')').attr('class','video1');
$('.video li:nth-of-type('+(((click+2)<=5) ? (click+2) : (click+2-5))+')').attr('class','video2');
$('.video li:nth-of-type('+(((click+3)<=5) ? (click+3) : (click+3-5))+')').attr('class','video3');
$('.video li:nth-of-type('+(((click+4)<=5) ? (click+4) : (click+4-5))+')').attr('class','video4');
})
})
//播放完后

//控制条
function mouseOver1() {
  var video=document.getElementById("v001");
  video.controls=true;
}
function mouseOut1() {
  var video=document.getElementById("v001");
  video.controls=false;
}
function mouseOver2() {
  var video=document.getElementById("v002");
  video.controls=true;
}
function mouseOut2() {
  var video=document.getElementById("v002");
  video.controls=false;
}
function mouseOver3() {
  var video=document.getElementById("v003");
  video.controls=true;
}
function mouseOut3() {
  var video=document.getElementById("v003");
  video.controls=false;
}
function mouseOver4() {
  var video=document.getElementById("v004");
  video.controls=true;
}
function mouseOut4() {
  var video=document.getElementById("v004");
  video.controls=false;
}
function mouseOver5() {
  var video=document.getElementById("v005");
  video.controls=true;
}
function mouseOut5() {
  var video=document.getElementById("v005");
  video.controls=false;
}
```

```css
.Lunbo-video{
    /* background-color:#dc2626; */
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
}
.Lunbo-video .Lunbo-video-title{
    margin:20px auto 50px;
}

.Lunbo-video .Lunbo-video-title .Lunbo-video-h1{
    font-size:30px;
    color:#ef7700;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
}
.Lunbo-video .Lunbo-video-title .Lunbo-video-h3{
    font-size:30px;
    color:#ef7700;
    text-align: center;
}
.Lunbo-video .Lunbo-video-cont{
    margin-bottom:50px;
    height: 100%;
}
.Lunbo-video li{
    list-style: none;
}
.video{
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    zoom:1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
     background: #ffffff; 
}
.video>div{
    float: left;
    height: 509px;
}
.video>div:first-child {
    width: 5%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    /* background: url('image\left.png') center center/cover no-repeat; */
}
.Lunbobutton{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.video>div:last-child {
    width: 5%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    /* background: rgb(240, 13, 114); */
    /* background: url('image\right.png') center center no-repeat; */
}
.video>div:nth-of-type(2){
    width: 90%;
}
.video ul{
    position: relative;
}
.video li{
    transition: all .6s;
    position: absolute;
    background: url(../images/video-bg.png) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;}
/*.video li>div{padding: 1% 1% 4%;}*/
.video li video{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.video li h3{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2px;
    color: #1766d7;
}

.video1{
    width:18%;
    height: auto;
    /* top: 143px; */
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    }/*创建5个播放框初始位置*/
.video2{
    width: 37%;
    height: auto;
    /* top: 86px; */
    left: 8%;
    z-index: 2;
}
.video3{
    width: 64%;
    height: auto;
    /* top: 0px; */
    left: 17%;
    z-index: 3;
}
.video4{
    width: 37%;
    height: auto;
    /* top: 86px; */
    left: 54%;
    z-index: 2;
}
.video5{
    width:18%;
    height: auto;
    /* top: 143px; */
    left: 82%;
    z-index: 1;}
```

```html
<div class="Lunbo-video">
              <div class="Lunbo-video-title">
                <h1 class="Lunbo-video-h3 text-center">急救小视频</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="Lunbo-video-cont">
                <div class="video">
                  <div> <img src="images/left.png" class="Lunbobutton"> </div>
                  <div>
                  
                   <ul>
                      <li class="video1"><div><video id="v001" onmouseover="mouseOver1()" onmouseout="mouseOut1()" src="video/zhixi.mp4" preload="auto" poster="images/t1zhixi.png"></video></div> </li>
                      <li class="video2"><div><video id="v002" onmouseover="mouseOver2()" onmouseout="mouseOut2()" src="video/yundao.mp4" preload="auto" poster="images/t2yundao.jpg"></video></div> </li>
                      <li class="video3"><div><video id="v003" onmouseover="mouseOver3()" onmouseout="mouseOut3()" src="video/yundao.mp4" preload="auto" poster="images/t3yundao.png"></video> </div></li>
                      <li class="video4"><div><video id="v004" onmouseover="mouseOver4()" onmouseout="mouseOut4()" src="video/zhixi.mp4" preload="auto" poster="images/t4.png"></video> </div></li>
                      <li class="video5"><div><video id="v005" onmouseover="mouseOver5()" onmouseout="mouseOut5()" src="video/zhixi.mp4" preload="auto" poster="images/t1zhixi.png"></video> </div></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div><img src="images/right.png" class="Lunbobutton"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```